# How do you run manual tasks within a Meteor project?

Tags: meteor, rake, task

For example, in a **Ruby** project you can use `rake` to create and run tasks for performing manual operations. What is the equivalent, if any, when using **Meteor**?

Let's say I have a function inside a `server/tasks.js` file:

```
Meteor.startup(function() {

  function importData() {
    // My code goes here
  }
});
```

How do I run it from the command line using Meteor or some other task manager?

```
meteor importData
```

Comment: Might have an answer, but can you give some examples of what you' like to run? Is it custom tasks that you define in your Meteor code, which you'd like to be able to call from the CLI?

Comment: Yes, I'd like to create a data import function in one of my server files that will be used occasionally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved a similar case by creating a Meteor method on the serverside that is triggered every time a client loads a page that needs the data. The method only executes the importData function if it hasn't been executed in the last hour.

This is a good pattern for things dat need to sync with remote data. I use it for importing stuff from Tumblr. The downside of this approach is that the method is not run when nobody visits the page. This is easily solved by adding a timer using Meteor.setInterval on the serverside.

Alternatively, if you really want to execute Meteor code from the command prompt, you could take a look at the following package:
https://github.com/practicalmeteor/meteor-mcli